# Unix script to print file in upper case and lower case

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file that contains 5000 records mainly names like

```
david
mathew
philip
```

I am looking for a script to read that file and create an ouptut like

```
insert into names_db values(david,DAVID);
insert into names_db values(mathew,MATHEW);
insert into names_db values(philip,PHILIP);
```

Comment: If you are inserting in a database you probably need them quoted: `insert ... ('david', 'DAVID');`

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '{printf "insert into names_db values(%s,%s);\n", tolower($0), toupper($0)}' file
insert into names_db values(david,DAVID);
insert into names_db values(mathew,MATHEW);
insert into names_db values(philip,PHILIP);
```

Answer (score 1):

A single sed will do this job. You don't need to create a script.

```
sed 's/.\+/insert into names_db values(&,\U&);/g' file
```

`&` refers all the matched characters. `\U&` would turn all the matched characters to uppercase.

**OR**

```
$ sed 's/.*/insert into names_db values(&,\U&);/g' file
insert into names_db values(david,DAVID);
insert into names_db values(mathew,MATHEW);
insert into names_db values(philip,PHILIP);
```

Answer (score 0):

This very simple solution uses only Bash for case modification during parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

stmt="insert into names_db values(%s,%s);\n"

while read name
do
  printf "$stmt" "$name" "${name^^}"
done < test.txt
```

Search `bash(1)` for `\^\^` for more information. Note that Bash 4.x or higher is required.